# could not convert string to float: '2022-03-18'

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I cannot understand why it gives the error, i tried to use df=df.astype(float) before "df.plot.line(x='Date',y='Hits',ylabel='Views',figsize=(10,5),title='Wiki PageView Trend for ' + keyword)", however it gives only that "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2022-03-18'"

Please help! Thanks in advance!

```
!pip3 install pytrends

import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

keyword="hybrid office"
url = f'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=pageviews&titles={keyword}&format=json'

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
getjson = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Date', 'Hits'])

for k,item in getjson['query']['pages'].items():
  for j,value in item['pageviews'].items():
    data = {'Date': j, 'Hits': value}
    df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)

df.plot.line(x='Date',y='Hits',ylabel='Views',figsize=(10,5),title='Wiki PageView Trend for ' + keyword)
```

Here is the error -->

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-b131ce503630> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df.plot.line(x='Date',y='Hits',ylabel='Views',figsize=(10,5),title='Wiki PageView Trend for ' + keyword)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py in _compute_plot_data(self)
    451         # no non-numeric frames or series allowed
    452         if is_empty:
--> 453             raise TypeError("no numeric data to plot")
    454 
    455         self.data = numeric_data.apply(self._convert_to_ndarray)

TypeError: no numeric data to plot
```

Comment: dates are not floats. Try using `.astype("datetime64[ns]")` instead of `float`

Comment: Seems like you need to check what's stored in the `Date` column. I'm guessing that it doesn't expect the x-axis to be string. Maybe try `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` before calling `df.plot`